# Playing Multiple Video Nodes at the same Time - Roku SDK

Tags: roku, brightscript, scenegraph

I am trying to overlay two video screens and play them simultaneously, with the audio on one muted. However, it seems like Roku only supports the playback of one Video at a time. Is there any way to play both Video nodes simultaneously? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it may not be possible :( https://forums.roku.com/viewtopic.php?t=112791

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. I tried several things to make it work but without any success. So for now this is not an option.

Comment: Hey @U.Mitic Is there any way to find a multiple AudioTrack in Roku. I used https://github.com/ctraganos/roku-sdk/blob/master/examples/source/video-layout-examples/components/MultipleAudioTrackVideo.xml this example for Finding a AudioTrack. I also put Stack overflow question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59488615/play-multipleaudiotrack-in-roku.