# Play MultipleAudioTrack in Roku

Tags: audio, video-streaming, roku, audiotrack, brightscript

I know about Roku doesn't support multiple videos at a time. But, Some Developers are mix up two things multiple playbacks and multiple audio tracks. Roku Does Support Multiple Audio Track?

I tried to Play MultipleAudioTrack in Roku. I used the below code to find a multiple audio track Here `?"m.video.availableAudioTracks :"m.video.availableAudioTracks` but here not available any track. my stream check-in VLC MediaPlayer. Here two-track available. But, I not found in Roku. My Audio Format is AAC. I also Set Here `m.video.audioFormat = "aac"`. Any other Configuration required to Playing a multiple Audio.

My m3u8 file is below.

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:9
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:1
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXTINF:8,
RokuMedia00000001.ts
#EXTINF:8,
RokuMedia00000002.ts
#EXTINF:8,
RokuMedia00000003.ts
```

Is there any configuration required for the m3u8 file.

I read the HLS [Documentation](https://developer.roku.com/docs/developer-program/media-playback/trick-mode/hls-and-dash.md#example-playlists) which is provided by Roku. But, I have still some doubts regarding HLS Stream. I used the Roku Premiere plus device.

[image]

For CC, I enable Closed Captions options using coding it's below.

```
m.videoContent.streamformat = "hls"
m.videoContent.subtitleTracks = [{ language: "EN", description: "EN", trackName: "eia608/1" }]
m.videoContent.subtitleConfig = { trackName: "eia608/1" }
```

It's not available in M3u8 file content. It's available on my ts File. I mention my M3u8 Content in the above.

Same way, I tried to enable Multiple Audio Track using Coding.

I used Following Field For fetching a multiple Audio Track.

```
?"m.video.availableAudioTracks :"m.video.availableAudioTracks
m.video.audioFormat = "aac"
```

I refer to [this](https://github.com/ctraganos/roku-sdk/blob/master/examples/source/video-layout-examples/components/MultipleAudioTrackVideo.xml) example of playing a Multiple Audio Track.

I used the aac audio format for playing audio in the Roku video player.

I check the same M3u8 File in other Video Player(VLC, IOS inbuilt player, EXO Player) It takes automatically shows two audio track.

[image]

I'm not sure. But, I think Roku Video player Compalsary required multiple Audio tracks in M3u8 File. Like below. Is it Correct?

```
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="aac",NAME="English",LANGUAGE="en",AUTOSELECT=YES,\
DEFAULT=YES,URI="RokuMedia00000001.ts"

#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="aac",NAME="Spanish",LANGUAGE="es-ES",AUTOSELECT=NO,\
DEFAULT=NO,URI="RokuMedia00000001.ts"
```

But, Here It possible to Put the EXT-X-MEDIA tag in Two Times?

or I don't know which specific field will add I required.

**I found one article in the Roku  Knowledge Center article [Does Roku support multiple audio tracks](https://partnersuccess.roku.com/hc/en-us/articles/360048834873-Does-Roku-support-multiple-audio-tracks-?source=search&auth_token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJhY2NvdW50X2lkIjoxMDkyMzgyLCJ1c2VyX2lkIjo0MTEwNDYwODYwMTQsInRpY2tldF9pZCI6NDAxNzUsImNoYW5uZWxfaWQiOjYzLCJ0eXBlIjoiU0VBUkNIIiwiZXhwIjoxNTkyNTkwNTYxfQ.K_IS4ES7a_iRZ67ZwCyUBCO-UWuyeqWAr9iChYGryhE)?**

But, I'm not required to enable multiple audio tracks at the same time. or also not required to playing simultaneously. I required to at a time only a single audio track. Because, I know any media player not support multiple audio track and video track the same time.

**I required to change the audio track at run time. If my default track in English and using this option, I  change to It Spanish or any else.**

My Actual question is a how-to enable audio track option which provide by Roku and which fields are required in m3u8 files. To enable these options. or Roku has stopped supporting audiotrack options?

Comment: If not mistaken, if Your stream manifest has two audio tracks You should be able to see it in default ROKU menu by pressing * on the remote. I think the option is called available audio tracks or something like that. Anyhow, are You able to see two tracks in that menu?

Comment: Yes I check. but not available. I also check same stream in vlc media player here i found but in roku not available.

Comment: @U.Mitic I refer to this https://github.com/ctraganos/roku-sdk/blob/master/examples/source/video-layout-examples/components/MultipleAudioTrackVideo.xml example. Here I check with my stream but not able to find multiple audio tracks using this example.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not certain about Audio files, but I know that [Rokus don't allow you to buffer more than one Video at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50651962/playing-multiple-video-nodes-at-the-same-time-roku-sdk). This effectively means that a Roku cannot play more than one Video at a time.

The same could be true for audio files but I am not certain.

Comment: I refer to this https://github.com/ctraganos/roku-sdk/blob/master/examples/source/video-layout-examples/components/MultipleAudioTrackVideo.xml example. Here I check with my stream but not able to find multiple audio tracks using this example.

Answer (score 1):

Roku does not support 2 or more parallel audios.
You have to stop one audio to play some another audio.

you can do it like

```
m.firstAudio.contorl = "stop"
m.secondAudio.contorl = "play"
```

note that you have to stop it not mute.